# how to parse the values inside of an object that comes from an ajax get request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, parsing

I have a variable object type that I am getting from an Ajax get request and I want to use the values inside a table row inside of that object.

```
$.get(url2, function (responseGET) {
      var responseGETHtml2 = $(responseGET).find(".data-item-form form.form");
 
      console.log("responseGETHtml2", responseGETHtml2);
```

Output:

```
k.fn.init [form.form.default-form, prevObject: k.fn.init(91)]
0: form.form.default-form
length: 1
prevObject: k.fn.init(91) [text, meta, text, title, text, comment, comment, comment, meta, text, meta, text, meta, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, link, text, header, article, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, span, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, script, text]
__proto__: Object(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()` to see the HTML contents of the element.

```
console.log("responseGETHtml2", responseGETHtml2.html());
```

Comment: it worked, but then how I get the values inside of the table without using split?

Comment: Use `responseGETHtml2.find("tr")` to get a table row, then loop through them. Just like operating on the DOM.

Comment: i dont know how it works. when i do $(responseGETHtml2).find("tr"), i get the same result as the start : k.fn.init [prevObject: k.fn.init(19)]

Comment: Just like in the answer, you have to use `.html()` or `.text()` to get the contents of the element. You're logging the jQuery object itself.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance but when i do  console.log("tr", $(responseGETHtml2).find("tr").html()); , i get: undefined

Comment: Then there's no `tr` element in the response HTML. I assumed there would be since you said this is a table. If you add a sample of the returned HTML to the question I might have a better idea.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just have the API return JSON, rather than scraping HTML?